# Angels visiting Abraham during Pesach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, passover, rashi, chametz-leaven, vayera

I start it from the end: regarding Lot it is written ([Bereishit 19:3](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0119.htm#3)):

> וַיִּפְצַר־בָּ֣ם מְאֹ֔ד וַיָּסֻ֣רוּ אֵלָ֔יו וַיָּבֹ֖אוּ אֶל־בֵּית֑וֹ וַיַּ֤עַשׂ לָהֶם֙ מִשְׁתֶּ֔ה **וּמַצּ֥וֹת אָפָ֖ה** וַיֹּאכֵֽלוּ׃
> And he urged them greatly; and they turned in unto him, and entered into his house; and he made them a feast, **and did bake unleavened bread,** and they did eat.

Rashi [says there](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214/showrashi/true#v3) that it was passover, moreover, he [adds](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214/showrashi/true#v1) that it didn't took much time for the angels to get there from Hebron, so it can be assumed that it was *erev pesach* the earliest when the angels visited Abraham. This fits well with the words of the *gemara* in Rosh haShanah 10b–11a, where both [Rabbi Eliezer](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.10b.10) and [Rabbi Yehoshua](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.11a.2) say that Isaac was born on passover (and his birth was [announced](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#10) a year in advance). [Berakhot 27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.27a.10) concludes that it was noon when the visitors arrived to Abraham, and [Bereishit Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.48.12) [48:12](https://archive.org/details/RabbaGenesis/page/n461) explicitly says that Sarah made unleavened bread for passover.

How comes then Rashi to comment on [Bereishit 18:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/jewish/Chapter-18.htm/showrashi/true#v6) that

> **קמח סלת –** סֹלֶת לְעֻגוֹת, **קֶמַח לַעֲמִילָן שֶׁל טַבָּחִים**, לְכַסּוֹת אֶת הַקְּדֵרָה לִשְׁאֹב אֶת הַזֻּהֲמָא.‏
> **meal [and] fine flour –** The fine flour for the cakes [and] the meal for **the starch used by cooks** to cover the pot, to draw out the scum.

when it is known that this cook's dough is not allowed on passover ([Mishnah Pesachim 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.3.1); [gemara 42b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.42b.15))?

Comment: Although note that Rosh Hashana 11a seems to assume that the angels came in Tishrei

Comment: @JoelK I haven't learned this yet, but I can't figure out why the angels' visit and the conception had to coincide in time.

Comment: The [Tur HaAroch](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.6?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Tur_HaArokh%2C_Genesis.18.6.1&lang2=he) and [Megaleh Amukos](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=106584&pagenum=34) (on Bereishis, ד"ה יש כאן) address this question, but I don't understand their answers.

Comment: See [Rashi HaShalem](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/143982/p/222/t/7142805321885312341234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to make it kosher for pesach.