# Did Avrohom own חמץ on פסח?

Tags: passover, malach-angel, abraham, bread

In Gensis 18 -6, when Avrohom hosted the angels, he told his wife to

> מַֽהֲרִ֞י שְׁל֤שׁ סְאִים֙ קֶ֣מַח סֹ֔לֶת ל֖וּשִׁי וַֽעֲשִׂ֥י עֻגֽוֹת:
>
> "Hasten three seah of meal [and] fine flour; knead and make cakes."

Rashi explains that the inferior 'meal' wasn't for their consumption but rather to make a starchy covering for the cooking pot.

> קמח סלת: סלת לעוגות, קמח לעמלן של טבחים, לכסות את הקדרה, ולשאוב את
> הזוהמא:

The problem is that this starch like form is not allowed to be owned on פסח and is explicitly listed in the first משנה of אלו עוברים.  https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=42&format=pdf.

It is a well documented question when this event took place, but most hold that it was on פסח. There are opinions saying it was sukkos (even bringing support from another Rashi), but how do the פסח camp square this question?

I wonder if it is possible to make a starchy dough by using liquid that doesn't cuase leavaning?

Comment: This question is even stronger because Rashi himself says it was Pesach (Genesis 19:3).

Comment: Duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/126744/15256

Comment: @Kazibácsi did you ever get an answer elsewhere?

Comment: this begs a couple of interrelated questions -- the first is whether the Avot were bound by the mitzvot, and that has been discussed in many places. The second (to my mind) is whether it would have been possible to be bound by a mitzvah that commemorated a historical event which had not happened yet.

Comment: As you say this is a whole discussion in itself.
The gemaro (think it yumo somehwere between 25 - 30?) says that Avrohom kept all the torah + derabonons.
My question is based on that presumption.

Comment: Yuma 28b. Though I still have questions about #611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked around and a a talmid chochom pointed me to the מושב זקנים who asks and answers as follows:

1. The 'starch lid' may have been made and baked (without rising) before יו"ט > The טור adds that the rising הבל is not מחמיץ.
2. The flour may have been a rice flour